# What are the performance and pitfalls of String.sub

Tags: string, ocaml

I'm considering using `String.sub` for a task on a hot path that inserts multiple elements inside a large string at arbitrary positions.

Knowing that this kind of function always has gotchas in other languages, I'd like to know what those are in the standard OCaml implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.sub` (like most of the string manipulating functions) [allocates a new string and copies the contents of the original string](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/9924db8cf75e4328bf3070211b3d0e0c251eb1d0/stdlib/bytes.ml#L64-L71). So, it might be pretty slow if it is in a hot path.

Comment: Copying the string may be okay depending on how it's done.How is the access to the positions it's copying? Linear or sub-linear? unsafe_blit is external and I can't find the source.

Comment: [It is implemented in terms of `memmove`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/1c4e822bed72bfedddb3f7f4ff673a80716a2e03/byterun/str.c#L363-L368). It's hard to tell if it works for you, but if you are cutting and concatenating lots of strings, you can try an abstraction that tracks offsets & length (e.g. [CCString.Sub](https://c-cube.github.io/ocaml-containers/2.2/containers/CCString/Sub/index.html), or ropes).

Comment: It's more likely the insertion into a large string slows you done if done wrong. So it's hard to say if the String.sub is relevant without seeing the code surrounding it.